# synchronized access to HttpSession attribute vs static ConcurrentMap with HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, concurrency, servlets

As a part of [library implementing websocket Guice scopes](https://github.com/morgwai/servlet-scopes) I need to maintain an object related to each `HttpSession` called `sessionContextAttributes`. Currently `sessionContextAttributes` is stored as an attribute of a session, which means the access and initialization needs to be synchronized:

```java
ConcurrentMap<Key<?>, Object> getHttpSessionContextAttributes() {
    HttpSession session = getHttpSession();
    try {
        synchronized (session) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            var sessionContextAttributes = (ConcurrentMap<Key<?>, Object>)
                session.getAttribute(SESSION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            if (sessionContextAttributes == null) {
                sessionContextAttributes = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
                session.setAttribute(SESSION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, sessionContextAttributes);
            }
            return sessionContextAttributes;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new OutOfScopeException(/* ... */);
    }
}

static final String SESSION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME =
        ContainerCallContext.class.getPackageName() + ".contextAttributes";
```

Now I'm considering to maintain a static `ConcurrentMap` from `HttpSession` to `sessionContextAttributes` like this:

```java
static final ConcurrentMap<HttpSession, ConcurrentMap<Key<?>, Object>> sessionCtxs =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

ConcurrentMap<Key<?>, Object> getHttpSessionContextAttributes() {
    try {
        return sessionCtxs.computeIfAbsent(
                getHttpSession(), (ignored) -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new OutOfScopeException(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

This simplifies `getHttpSessionContextAttributes()` method and is probably slightly faster, **BUT** introduces static data **AND** requires manual removal to prevent leaking of `sessionContextAttributes`:

```java
static class SessionContextJanitor implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        sessionCtxs.remove(event.getSession());  // this avoids resource leaks
    }
}
```

I cannot confidently tell which approach is better: both have pros&cons. Hence I'm posting it here for review: maybe someone knows some reasons that make 1 of these approaches significantly better than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research and thinking, it turned out that both of the above approaches are wrong ;-]
The reason for both cases is that user `Filter`s may put `HttpSession` object into a wrapper, so neither synchronizing on it nor using it as a key in a `ConcurrentHashMap` is safe :/
Furthermore, in case of "*maintaining a static `ConcurrentMap`*" solution, `sessionContextAttributes` would not get serialized together with its session for example when sharing between cluster nodes or temporarily storing on disk to use memory for other requests.

Instead, I use `HttpSessionListener` to create and store the new context as a session attribute:

```java
ConcurrentMap<Key<?>, Object> getHttpSessionContextAttributes() {
    try {
        return (ConcurrentMap<Key<?>, Object>)
                getHttpSession().getAttribute(SESSION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new OutOfScopeException(/* ... */);
    }
}

static class SessionContextCreator implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setAttribute(
            SESSION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,
            new ConcurrentHashMap<Key<?>, Object>()
        );
    }
}
```

While it is not explicitly stated in the spec that `sessionCreated(...)` will be called on the same thread that first created the session with `request.getSession()`, it is kinda implied and both Tomcat and Jetty do so. Last but not least, certain Spring utilities assume that this is always the case.
Further discussions about this:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158685/is-httpsessionlistener-sessioncreated-guaranteed-to-complete-before-any-other),
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051883/is-sessioncreated-from-a-httpsessionlistener-automatically-synchronized-with-r),
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802165/is-synchronization-within-an-httpsession-feasible)

Comment: Instead of `} catch (NullPointerException e) {` comment maybe just `if (getHttpSession() != null) ...`? (or some direct `session` check if  it is getter's implementation dependend)

Comment: @Azahe NPE there is a result of a bug in the app that uses this library: it should be eliminated during development, so there's no point to check it every time in production where it will never happen. I catch it only to throw `RuntimeException` with [a message that explains how to fix this bug](https://github.com/morgwai/servlet-scopes/blob/v6.1-javax/src/main/java/pl/morgwai/base/servlet/scopes/ContainerCallContext.java#L49). See this article for further discussion on the topic: https://dzone.com/articles/why-i-never-null-check-parameters

Comment: @Azahe in the post here the handling has been replaced with the comment not to bother ppl with reading code that is not related to the core of the question ;-)

Comment: As much as I love the premise of article you mentioned (and consider it a standard approach at my workplace) I don't think that it any way justifies this way of handling programming errors. 
Note that the main idea of the article is to get rid of null checks ***by better design of the code*** - so here catching null pointer is IMO misappropriation of the idea as you are not eliminating the possibility of null pointer via redesigning library api so that making the known mistake impossible (like in the article's example with method parameters).

Comment: @Azahe you are correct, unfortunately the only way to eliminate possibility of this error would be to force session creation for every request starting a websocket connection: it is not acceptable in many cases and I didn't want to limit applicability of this lib. Reasons may be technical (cookies disabled, non-browser clients that don't even follow redirections), legal (user explicitly refusing any data storage) and probably others. Notifying developer ASAP about the issue with a clear message, was the best I could think of without compromising applicability. i's a sad trade-off basically...

Comment: @Azahe ...between API safety and lib applicability. This way developer can choose a solution that best suits him: either forcing a session creation with a filter (if it's acceptable in his case) or checking if the session exists and using app specific work-around instead of session-scoped objects (using websokcet connection scope instead will probably be acceptable in many situations).<br>
(normal servlets are immune to this error as it's possible to create a session on demand from `HttpServletRequest`, but there's no such possibility when processing a single websocket message)

Comment: Maybe make a separate post for this trade off? :D Will probably require establishing more context but seems like nice topic.